# How to write procedure with same no. of parameter in Oracle & SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, stored-procedures

SQL Server stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROC proc1
AS
SELECT ename FROM employee
```

Oracle Server stored procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE proc1
(
cv_1 IN OUT SYS_REFCURSOR
)
AS
BEGIN
OPEN cv_1 FOR
SELECT ename
FROM employee ;
END;
```

Is it possible to write this procedure in both Oracle & SQL Server with same number of parameter with same supported data type?

If possible how? and so how to call from both oracle & SQL Server?

Comment: Why do you need this? Can you create views instead of the procedures?

Comment: In my experience, you not gonna win the MS vs Oracle (w refcursor) "battle".  I'd love to be wrong, but I don't think so.

Comment: Check out this example that I wrote.  It provides a "safety valve" for when the 2 RDMBS' don't overlap perfectly.  Aka, you should be able to get most of your code the same, but if you can't, there is a way to do it that is not "if rdbmsType=rdbms.Oracle then"..............       http://granadacoder.wordpress.com/2008/03/04/multiple-rdbms-support-and-the-factory-design-pattern/

Answer (score 0):

We do this all the time and it works great however our systems are based on ODBC using the ODBC "Call" syntax to invoke procedures.  I believe this feature was added to the Oracle driver circa Oracle 10.

For example:

{CALL proc1} 
or if proc1 has non ref cursor parameters
{CALL proc1(parm1,parm2,parm3)}

Oracle driver automatically does what is necessary to convert ref cursor(s) into result set(s).  I believe there is/was an ordering dependancy in that the cursor parameter(s) need to be positioned last after any normal input parameters other than that you can have the same code returning result sets (using exact same query string to call procedures between SQL Server and Oracle)